# Pass submitted form value to a new view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In my Django app I have an index view with a `ModelChoiceField` for choosing an object. When I click the submit button I want to pass that object over to the next view, but it doesn't work.

**This is my code:**
views:

```
def index(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.POST:
            form = EquipmentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                request.session['chosen_equipment'] = form.cleaner(self)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/lru/reservation/')            
        else:
            form = EquipmentForm()
        args['form'] = form
        args['user'] = request.user
        args['reservation_list'] = Reservation.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('lru/index.html', args)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/lru/login/')

def reservation(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/lru/')
    else:
        form = ReservationForm()

    form = ReservationForm(initial={'reserved_by': request.user})
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    args['chosen_equipment'] = request.session.get('chosen_equipment', ' Not found')

    return render_to_response('lru/reservation.html', args)
```

forms:

```
class EquipmentForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = Equipment

    equipment = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Equipment.objects.all())

    def cleaner(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data[equipment]
            return data
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not really detailed. Could you describe your problem? Error?

Comment: Redirect to a `EquipmentPage` view that takes an id. Kinda like this `HttpResponseRedirect('myEquipment/{id_of_equipment_here}/')` and within that view you fetch the equipment chosen and show it there.

Comment: @hieu Of course. Im not getting any errors, but when I call request.session.get in my reservation view it just returns 'Not found' and not my object. I think I might be using either sessions or cleaned_data the wrong way.

Comment: Well to start off with your indentation is wrong.

Comment: @limelights Sorry, I don't follow. How can I reference the equipment id? Do you have a more detailed example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this version, which should do what you expect:

You don't need a separate method in your `forms.py`:

```
class EquipmentForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = Equipment

    equipment = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Equipment.objects.all())
```

In your `views.py`, this should work:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    args = {}
    args['user'] = request.user
    args['reservation_list'] = Reservation.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.POST:
            form = EquipmentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                request.session['chosen_equipment'] = form.cleaned_data['equipment']
                return redirect('/lru/reservation/')
            else:
                # Form invalid, so render the same view again
                args['form'] = form
                return render(request, 'lru/index.html', args)            
        else:
            form = EquipmentForm()
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'lru/index.html', args)
    else:
        return redirect('/lru/login/')

@login_required
def reservation(request):
    args = {}
    args['chosen_equipment'] = request.session.get('chosen_equipment', ' Not found')
    if request.POST:
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/lru/')
        else:
            # Always have an else condition if the form doesn't validate
            args['form'] = form
            return render(request, 'lru/reservation.html', args)
    else:

        form = ReservationForm(initial={'reserved_by': request.user})
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'lru/reservation.html', args)
```

Changes:

1. No need for a custom method, as you can access `cleaned_data` in the view.
2. Used the `redirect` shortcut, which is a lot more flexible.
3. Used the `render` shortcut so that `RequestContext` is passed correctly.
4. Added the code for the case where the form isn't validated.
5. Added the `login_required` decorator to ensure the view only gets called with a logged in user.

Comment: Why not just `redirect('/lru/reservation'+reservation_id)` and have the reservation detail view fetch the object instead of storing it in the session? Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Because that way you can bypass the form; which may be required - as the case is here there is an item being written to the database.

Comment: How can you bypass the form? The form must be valid for saving the object in the first place and when the form is validated and saved the redirect happens?

Comment: By simply browsing to `/lru/reservation/` (insert random number)

Comment: Okay, I see your point, and it's wise, but I disagree (but willing to change my mind ;) ) because a) `login_required`& `is_authenticated` and b) the filtering of Equipment objects should be done with `Eq.objects.get(pk=pk, user=user)`. My conceptual reasoning is this: http://dpaste.com/1327857/